# Aligning fans in a tube

Tags: fluid-dynamics, fan

So, I have **a lot** of old PC fans and got thinking, what would the airflow look like if I lined them all up in a straight tube and powered them all? Would the speed of the airflow increase a steady amount as it passes each fan? Would it not change at all? Would it increase for a few fans, but not accomplish much because the motors can only push so much air?

Comment: The speed of the air is going to be essentially the same from one end of the pipe from the other, because the same amount of air is entering the pipe as is leaving it, and I assume we are talking about a constant diameter pipe.

I assume then that you are asking about how that speed depends on the number of fans in the pipe?

Comment: One thing to contemplate is just _how_ a fan moves air.